# Similarity transformation of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, density-operator

Consider a $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian as $H=p_x\sigma_x$.
Which is not in its diagonal form, which implies it is not written in its eigenbasis. Now consider I have an observable, which has the matrix form as $J_x=\sigma_x$. I want to find the expectation value of the observable $J_x$, which is simply $Tr(J_x\rho)$. Now, the density matrix($\rho$) is known in the Hamiltonian's eigenbasis. Let's assume
$\rho=p_G|G\rangle \langle G|+p_E|E\rangle \langle E|$, where $|G\rangle$ and $|E\rangle$ are the two eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

If I consider an ordered basis $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$, then the Hamiltonian can simply be written in terms of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ as $H=p_x(|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|)$. One can always find $|G\rangle=\alpha_0|0\rangle+\beta_0|1\rangle$ and $|E\rangle=\alpha_1|0\rangle+\beta_1|1\rangle$. Also, a matrix $U$ for which $U^{\dagger}HU$ will always be a diagonal. A simple calculation can show $U^{\dagger}HU=-p_x(|E\rangle\langle G|+|G\rangle\langle E|)$, which implies it is diagonal not in $|G\rangle$ and $\langle E|$, but in $|0\rangle$ and $\langle 1|$, where $|0\rangle$ and $\langle 1|$ are its new eigen vector. But how do we prove that from $-(|E\rangle\langle G|+|G\rangle\langle E|)$ is equivalent to $-|0\rangle\langle 0|+|1\rangle\langle 1|)$ not by doing matrix calculations but using Dirac notations?

Now the observable $J=\partial_{p_x}H=\sigma_{p_x}$, will be changed accordingly. The idea is the mean will not change in similarity transformation. So $\langle\psi|J|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}UJU^{\dagger}U|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|UU^{\dagger}JUU^{\dagger}|\psi\rangle$. Now when the Hamiltonian is already gone through the similarity transformation then why $U^{\dagger}JU$ is different from $\partial_{p_x}(U^{\dagger}HU)$?

What about the density matrix? As there, it is not observable, so the meaning of mean is not defined here. So, what will be the similarity transformation here $U^{\dagger}\rho U$ or $U\rho U^{\dagger}$? Given that I initially know $\rho$ in the eigenbasis of the initial Hamiltonian(hamiltonian before similarity transformation, as I mentioned in the first paragraph). I want to know it in $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ basis.

Comment: You always consider ordered bases if you work with matrices. You have to keep the same order for all vectors and matrices. The result for either choice is the same if you are consistent.

Comment: I know the basis I used to construct the hamiltonian need to be used consistently. I still have confusion. Considr the dirac hamiltonian in 2D, $H=p_x\sigma_x+p_y\sigma_y$. Consider the observable current, which $j=\nabla_pH$. The mean of current is $Tr(j\rho)$. Now how this $\rho$ will be determined, when I know what is its form in its eigenbasis(same as Hamiltonian's eigenbasis). From my question it can be seen than in two different representation trace will be different.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. No, the trace is basis-independent; if you get different results, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Let me clarify. For the observable in my question $A$, 
$Tr(A\rho)=a_{11}p_0+a_{22}p_1$ in the first representation. On the other representation it will be $Tr(A\rho)=a_{11}p_1+a_{22}p_0$. So it is clearly different, but it should not be the case. For the case of Dirac Hamiltonian in my previous comment, if I know $\rho=p_0|0\rangle\langle 0|+p_1|1\rangle\langle 1|$, then what will be its matrix representation?

Comment: You have to use everything consistent. I don't know what else to say. Write down your Hamiltonian in a fixed basis. Write down the density matrix in the same (ordered) basis. Compute the trace. You can then change the order of the basis, repeat and find the same result.

Comment: My Hamiltonian is already known in momentum space, i.e. Dirac Hamiltonian as I mentioned in my previous comment. For that $H=p_x\sigma_x+p_y\sigma_y$, if I know what the matrix elements are of the $H$. My question is very simple how I will determine what will be the matrix elements of $\rho$, if I know it is $\rho=p_0|0\rangle\langle 0|+p_1|1\rangle\langle 1|$.

Comment: As you keep ignoring my hints, I will stop here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148625/discussion-between-debamalya-dutta-and-tobias-funke).

Comment: Your operators $H$ and $A$ are not written in the same basis as your density matrix $\rho$. Write EVERYTHING in the same (ordered) basis, then you can traces as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If done correctly, the observable is independent of the basis it was calculated in.
Also, the $\hat\rho$ operator is independent of the basis, and $Tr[\hat\rho \hat A]$ for any observable $\hat A$ is independent of the basis provided that the basis is complete. This is actually the reason why in the expression $Tr[\hat\rho \hat A]$ there is no indication of any specific basis.

Now, for Dirac notation, let's clarify the difference between the operator and its components. First, operator is a thing like $|...\rangle\langle...|$, or a combination of such things. A component of such operator in a certain basis $(|\alpha_1\rangle, |\alpha_2\rangle, ...)$ would look like $A_{ij}^{(\alpha)}=\langle\alpha_i|...\rangle\langle...|\alpha_j\rangle$. The treatment is the same for the observable and for the density operator (since they are both just operators).

Next, lets look at what you are trying to compute:
$Tr[\hat\rho \hat A]=\sum_i \langle \alpha_i | \hat\rho \hat A | \alpha_i \rangle = \sum_i \sum_j \langle \alpha_i | \hat\rho| \alpha_j\rangle \langle \alpha_j |\hat A | \alpha_i \rangle = \sum_i \sum_j \rho_{ij}^{(\alpha)} A_{ji}^{(\alpha)}$, where the components are taken in the same basis.

If you have $\hat A$ in a different basis: $A_{ij}^{(\beta)}=\langle\beta_i|...\rangle\langle...|\beta_j\rangle$, you need to do the basis conversion:
$A_{ij}^{(\alpha)}=\langle\alpha_i| \sum_{kl} A_{kl}^{(\beta)} |\beta_k\rangle\langle\beta_l  |\alpha_j\rangle$ where the products like $\langle\beta_l  |\alpha_j\rangle$ should be easy to calculate if you know the relation between the basis vectors.